# How to performance tune oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

Can anyone recommend the best practices for Oracle DB query performance tuning?
Are there applications free or paid that would be industry standard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle comes with a tool called Explain Plan. What this gives you is some insight into what Oracle is going to do with a given query.

Some information regarding explain plan can be found at ORAFAQ: [Understanding Explain Plan](http://www.orafaq.com/node/1420)

Note that interpreting an explain plan is something that requires a bit of experience in the arts of database administration. Even finding which queries are the ones that need observation is a bit of an art form.

Answer (score 2):

The industry standard would be "it depends".

If you have the Enterprise Edition of the database and the Performance and Tuning Pack, Oracle provides a number of tools such as the SQL Tuning Advisor to help you tune a particular SQL statement.  It provides the AWR (Automatic Workload Repository) and ASH (Active Session History) tables and various utilities to report on and work with these tables to help you identify statements that need to be tuned or systemic issues.  It has advisors that help you tune your memory configurations.  There are many books devoted entirely to many of the different tools Oracle provides.

But there are also, generally, things that require a knowledgable human.  Automated tools can suggest that a query might benefit from an additional index.  A human can look at a query, understand the underlying data, and realize that the query itself could be rewritten to massively increase performance by using analytic functions rather than doing a bunch of self joins.  A human can recognize where the automated tools are likely to have problems and where it makes more sense to address an application issue such as a lack of bind variables.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of Oracle docs on this.

Here is some [SQL Tuning Overview](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/sql_1016.htm)

You shold understand what [Query Optimizer](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/optimops.htm#PFGRF001) does.

Read some [Performance Tuning](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/text.920/a96517/aoptim.htm).

On the high level it starts with adding indexes and switching between different types of joins.
But there is more weird sh*t behind it.

Comment: I any ** wants to downvote he/she should leave comment why. Thank you.